# Is "development(al) journey" a common metaphor in English, or is there a more idiomatic expression?

Tags: idiomatic-language, metaphors

As the heading suggests, I'm wondering whether "development(al) journey" is a common metaphor in English, or whether there is a more idiomatic expression for this. Neither NGrams nor google seems to really support this metaphor, so I suspect there is probably a more common/more idiomatic way of expressing this.

Examples:

> We support our students' development(al) journey.

> Accompanying your child on their development(al) journey may be both scary and fun.

Comment: A "development(al) journey" is **learning**. Please don't complicate English for learners, ahem, on their "developement(al) journey", or perhaps **learning experience**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you! And you'd say "development journey" and "developmental journey" work equally well?

Comment: No, you say it wasn't supported by NGrams. **Learning** is the more usual term. Note that a "development(al) journey" isn't a metaphor, but [psychobabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychobabble).

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh... so you're agreeing with my initial assumption that it **doesn't** work? That's too bad... Oh well... Psychobabble or not, I really need something more "poetic" than just "learning" or "learning experience", but perhaps there's no such thing then?

Comment: There might be. If you prefer a poetical phrase over idiomatic then perhaps [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go.

Comment: @WeatherVane Good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Developmental journey" is perfectly fine. You could say "learning," but the two have different meanings.

Without further context, "development" includes not just learning but also (say) improving one's social and emotional skills, as schools for young children try to do.